# Hover not working in Gmail & outlook 2007 in Email template

Tags: html, css, email, xslt, html-email

I have created an **Email template**, and it works correctly at gmail and outlook, the main problem that I have, is when I try to change a **color of a link** to **yellow** after **hovering** on it, it does not work, can you suggest for me a solution? and thanks

```css
.sommaireeLinks {
color:#F2F2F3 !important;
}
.sommaireeLinks a:link {
color:#F2F2F3 !important;
}

.sommaireeLinks a:hover {
color:#fdbf5a !important;
}

.sommaireeLinks a:visited {
color:#fdbf5a !important;
}
a:visited {
color:#fdbf5a !important;
}
```

```html
<li style="color: #F2F2F3; font-family: Cambria; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1em; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;margin-left:0;" class="">
 <span style="color:#FF0000; line-height:1.1em;margin-left:0;"><b><xsl:value-of select=""/></b></span><a href="#{$}" style="font-size: 10pt;font-family:Cambria; text-decoration: none; font-weight:normal;margin-left:0;;color:#F2F2F3"><xsl:value-of select="" /></a></li>
```

Comment: I think Gmail doesn't care about css... it takes only the inline css. You must try thins [CSS inliner](https://inliner.cm/)

Comment: yes, but how you can add a hover in inline css?

Comment: i think you can't, have you try using a CSS inliner?

Comment: Your list is missing the class `sommaireeLinks`. Add it in and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hover only works on these but not all Gmail platform.
AOL
Apple Mail
Yahoo Mail
Gmail

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a way of including hover effect. You can take reference from:

https://litmus.com/blog/interactive-email-for-beginners-6-interactive-elements-you-can-add-to-your-emails-today

Comment: Please dont post links to outside resources. Take the main parts of the page and put it in your answer. You can link it as a source if need be. Reason being if the page goes down this answer will no longer be usable.

Comment: The hover effect they cover only works for 
AOL
Apple Mail
Yahoo Mail
Gmail